# Should all/most methods in interfaces return Option?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Is it a good practice to make all interface (trait) methods for which there may exist a future implementation with invalid arguments returning an option?

Let me give an example. If I would implement a library for probability distributions with a trait

```
trait Similarity {
   def getDensity(): Double
}
```

Since most distributions are not defined over the whole real space, there are always some illegal parameters e.g. a non-positive variance for a Gaussian distribution. If I understood it correctly, I should return an `Option[Double]` rather than a `Double` and throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I think the same is true for most functions/calculations. What is "best practice" in this case? I am afraid this would make a library overly clumsy.

Thanks

Comment: If it's exceptional, it should be an exception. I guess it's not hard for a user of your API to ensure that the passed arguments fulfill the preconditions of the contract. If you use Option, you force your user to always check the result type before using it.

Comment: Of course, the counterargument to Niklas's reasoning is that if you throw an exception, then you force your user to handle the possibility of an exception; at least the Option makes it more obvious.

Comment: Especially with math libs, there are situations in which an algorithm calls the functions (e.g. numerical optimization). My fear is somehow, that using Option in a low-level position means that all calling functions have to be explicitly designed to handle Option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't throw an IllegalArgumentException as it is not the arguments that are the problem, but the state of the object.  If it were to be an exception, IllegalStateException would match.

However, the real answer depends on what you expect the caller to do in the case of a problem.

If they would themselves throw an exception, that's what you should do, saving them the bother.

If they would do something different based on the answer being impossible, an Option[Double] is a good indicator.

A possibility worth knowing of, but less likely to be useful, is Double.NaN, effectively a Null Object but for Doubles.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is mostly a question of style and intent.

There's actually nothing wrong with throwing an exception *if the error is actually an exceptional condition*. If you decide to go down the path of throwing an exception, I would recommend throwing an [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html), or some subclass of it that you write, since that's more indicative of what the problem is.

Is this the sort of error that could happen frequently, and is best handled by the caller? Or is this more of a rare situation that's best handled at an upper layer? Or maybe even an indicator of some more fundamental error, such as a data or coding problem?

For comparison, it's true that dividing an integer by 0 is invalid, but forcing everyone to deal with that every time they divide would get old quickly. This is especially true when you know for certain that the exception will not be thrown with the data you're giving it. Imagine writing `x / 2 + 5`:

```
// normally
x / 2 + 5

// divide returns Option[Int]
(x / 2).map(_ + 5).get

// divide returns Either[ArithmeticException, Int]
(x / 2).right.map(_ + 5).right.get
```

If this error is something the caller can and should handle, then `Option[Double]` or `Either[someErrorClass, Double]` would be good.

`Option` is nice if you don't care why it failed/is invalid, just that it is. It's also fairly easy for the caller to deal with.

`Either` is good if there are multiple reasons why it would fail, and it's important for the caller to know why. This can be slightly more difficult to deal with than `Option`, though.

Comment: There IS something wrong with throwing an Exception if this API is in a functional programing context, and if not, Exceptions being unchecked in scala makes it harder to make sure at compile time that all paths of execution make sense.

Comment: stew: I've never heard a compelling argument that exceptions and functional programming don't mix. Any references?

Comment: Forcing the caller to handle error conditions feels like trying to put checked exceptions back in the language. It certainly has its place; just not sure that this is the right place.

Comment: an exception is a goto.  If your method might throw an exception, you lose referential transparency, which is the essential test if a function is really pure.  You can no longer take a function application and replace it with its result instead of calling the function.  What is the result of a function which threw an exception?

Comment: I don't see any conflict with forcing a caller to handle error conditions and trying to design a proper API

Comment: stew: Can't you replace the function application with `throw ...`? That seems referentially transparent to me.

Comment: @stew I think dave gives a pretty convicing case with his division example. Another might be the `head` method on a `List`. Are we saying pure code can't use integer division or `head`?

Comment: what is the type of `throw ...` ? is it an Int?  can I really use `throw ArithmeticException` into a function which is expecting an Int as a parameter?  is `val x: Int = throw ArithmeticException` valid?

Comment: See also my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818427/is-either-the-equivalent-to-checked-exceptions)

Comment: @stew The type of `throw new Exception` is [`Nothing`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Nothing), which is a bottom type; a subtype of every other. Yes, `val x: Int = throw ArithmeticException ` compiles just fine. See section 11.3 of [Programming in Scala](http://amzn.com/0981531644).

Answer (score 2):

In general, for an API, I would return Double if it is always defined, Option[Double] if it is sometimes undefined for valid input values.  If it is undefined for invalid inputs, I'd use Either[someError,Double] where a Left would be returned for invalid input. (or Validation from scalaz which is similar to either).

Thinks I'd NOT do is ever return a null or throw an exception.  If you are going to return an Either where Left indicates an error, the error in the left can be a Throwable (such as IllegalArgumentException or IllegalStateException), but I'd avoid throwing it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers already given:

The `Option` type is not always the only option. And having most interfaces return an `Option` is certainly not desirable. Usually, it is only desirable in cases *where the caller can expect the method to return "nothing" sometimes*.

Designing a good API takes more thought. Look at your traits and classes. Are they complete if they cannot provide this or that property? - If they are not complete without a certain property, then the property should not be an `Option` value. Rather, you might say: If the property can't be provided, then the object will be of a different type.

For the sake of example, think of a grid that represents a board game map. Every field is represented by a `Cell` datatype. Some of the cells may have colors.

The first version of the API might look like this:

```
trait Cell {
  def color:Color
}
```

Now, at some point you notice that some cells don't have a color. Empty cells, for example. Or cells that only contain text, which is supposed to be rendered in the default GUI color.

So you end up considering this version:

```
trait Cell {
  def color:Option[Color] = None
}
```

Now, every `Cell` implementation is free to override the `color` property, if desired.
But that's not the only possible solution.

Think of this alternative:

```
trait Cell { }
trait ColoredCell extends Cell {
  def color:Color
}
```

Now, the *type* of cell determines if it has a color or not, and colored cells are forced to have a color.

Some code on the UI layer might contain a fragment like this:

```
...
val cell:Cell = grid cellAt coordinates
val uiComponent:JComponent = ...
cell match {
  case coloredCell:ColoredCell => uiComponent setColor coloredCell.color
  case _ => // No color assigned
}
```

This approach works best with immutable objects. They don't ever change, but rather return a new instance which represents the modified version.

For example, every cell might have a method that sets the color:

```
trait Cell {
  def withColor(color:Color):ColoredCell
}
```

It returns a new cell, which represents a copy of *this* cell, with a different color. Of course, we already know that this will be an instance of `ColoredCell`, so we put it in the method contract.

Sometimes, this approach can work well, but you should carefully check beforehand how well it will fit your model.