# Is Either the equivalent to checked exceptions?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Beginning in Scala and reading about `Either` I naturally comparing new concepts to something I know (in this case from Java). Are there any differences from the **concept** of checked exceptions and `Either`?

In both cases

- the possibility of failure is explicitly annotated in the method (`throws` or returning `Either`)
- the programmer can handle the error case directly when it occurs or move it up (returning again an `Either`)
- there is a way to inform the caller about the reason of the error

I suppose one uses for-comprehensions on `Either` to write code as there would be no error similar to checked exceptions.

I wonder if I am the only beginner who has problems to see the difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Either` can be used for more than just exceptions.  For example, if you were to have a user either type input for you or specify a file containing that input, you could represent that as `Either[String, File]`.

`Either` is very often used for exception handling.  The main difference between `Either` and checked exceptions is that control flow with `Either` is always explicit.  The compiler really won't let you forget that you are dealing with an `Either`; it won't collect `Either`s from multiple places without you being aware of it, everything that is returned must be an `Either`, etc..  Because of this, you use `Either` not when maybe something extraordinary will go wrong, but as a normal part of controlling program execution.  Also, `Either` does not capture a stack trace, making it much more efficient than a typical exception.

One other difference is that exceptions can be used for control flow.  Need to jump out of three nested loops?  No problem--throw an exception (without a stack trace) and catch it on the outside.  Need to jump out of five nested method calls?  No problem!  Either doesn't supply anything like this.

That said, as you've pointed out there are a number of similarities.  You can pass back information (though `Either` makes that trivial, while checked exceptions make you write your own class to store any extra information you want); you can pass the `Either` on or you can fold it into something else, etc..

So, in summary: although you can accomplish the same things with `Either` and checked exceptions with regards to explicit error handling, they are relatively different in practice.  In particular, `Either` makes creating and passing back different states really easy, while checked exceptions are good at bypassing all your normal control flow to get back, hopefully, to somewhere that an extraordinary condition can be sensibly dealt with.

Comment: Thanks. It is very interesting since nearly all examples I saw were talking about error handling. Unfortunately I couldn't tutorials discussing the other cases you mentioned.

Comment: Moreover, if you processing a list of things, say a list of emails with some validation function and catching an exception from this function, the whole list will fail (if you placed *catch* block somewhere out of the loop). In case of Either, you can collect all of the errors, not only the first one. Isn't the *exceptions for control flow* is antipattern?

Comment: @om-nom-nom - So place the catch block in the loop (or view-map-takeWhile on the Eithers).  This is not a fundamental difference.

Comment: So is one of the advantages, that I can chain functions returning/taking an Either, but I can't do it with Exceptions since they would 'break' the chain?

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt - You can chain with `Either` and with exceptions.  It's a little less work with `Either`.

Comment: "Also, Either does not capture a stack trace, making it much more efficient than a typical exception" it also makes it harder to debug and tell what went wrong. Performance is less relevant in exceptional circumstances that ought to happen relatively rarely. Even in FP context with Either it's not unusual too see stacktrace added back in, eg. `Either[Exception, ...]` in scala.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino - Sure, it's entirely possible to make your life difficult by wrapping some unusual error condition in an `Either` and totally losing track of where it came from.  Any dogmatic position that says "never use exceptions, only `Either`" or "never use `Either`, only exceptions" is likely to leave you with substantial problems compared to the situation where you use each for what they're great at.

Answer (score 3):

Either is equivalent to a checked exception in terms of the return signature forming an [exclusive disjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_disjunction). The result can be a thrown exception X or an A. However, throwing an exception isn't equivalent to returning one – the first is not referentially transparent.

Where Scala's Either is not (as of 2.9) equivalent is that a return type is positively biased, and requires effort to extract/deconstruct the Exception, Either is unbiased; you need to explicitly ask for the left or right value. This is a [topic of some discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-debate/K6wv6KphJK0/discussion), and in practice a bit of pain – consider the following three calls to Either producing methods

```
for {
  a <- eitherA("input").right
  b <- eitherB(a).right
  c <- eitherC(b).right
} yield c // Either[Exception, C]
```

you need to manually thread through the RHS. This may not seem that onerous, but in practice is a pain and somewhat surprising to new-comers.

Comment: good comment, but what do you mean with referentially transparent?

Comment: referential transparency means can we replace the expression with its value – an exception being thrown is a side-effect, it cannot be turned into a value. An Either value of Left[SomeException] is not thrown, and so is referentially transparent. A good explanation can be found here: http://blog.higher-order.com/blog/2012/09/13/what-purity-is-and-isnt/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Either` is a way to embed exceptions in a language; where a set of operations that can fail can throw an error value to some non-local site.

In addition to the practical issues Rex mentioned, there's some extra things you get from the simple semantics of an `Either`:

- `Either` forms a monad; so you can use monadic operations over sets of expressions that evaluate to `Either`. E.g. for short circuiting evaluation without having to test the result
- `Either` is in the type -- so the type checker alone is sufficient to track incorrect handling of the value

Once you have the ability to return either an error message `(Left s)` or a successful value `Right v`, you can layer exceptions on top, as just `Either` plus an error handler, as is done [for `MonadError` in Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html).